# Trigger build on pushing tag

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a build that triggers when commits are pushed to my master branch. These builds produce pre-release nuget packages. I would like to do a full release without a pre-release suffix when I push a tag. Is it possible to trigger some specific build/release (only) when a tag is pushed to a repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn’t the feature of trigger a build/release when a tag is pushed to the repo. The change is required.

The workaround is that:

1. Create/add a PowerShell file to source control to add build tag ([##vso[build.addbuildtag]build tag](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md)) per to the new tag of repo (logical: 1. [Get a list of tags](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/refs#include-statuses) 2. Compare them (e.g. creationData, tag name or compare it with old tags (can store in a file) 3. If meet your requirement 4. Add tag to build (##vso[build.addbuildtag]build tag))
2. Create a new build definition
3. Check `Continuous integration (CI)` option in Triggers tab and specify branch filters
4. Add PowerShell step to build definition and specify that PowerShell file
5. Create a new release definition
6. Check `Continuous Deployment` option in Triggers tab and specify `Set trigger on artifact source`, then click `Add` to add tags condition

After that the new release will be created if there is specific tag added to build.

About calling REST API with PowerShell, you can refer to: [Calling VSTS APIs with PowerShell](http://blog.devmatter.com/calling-vsts-apis-with-powershell/)

Answer (score 2):

Did you look at this thread https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/13326927-trigger-build-when-pushing-tag-to-git ?

Try to specify **refs/tags/*** in "Branch filters".

This works for me in simplest case - when I push any tag (but only to the head commit of the branch in my case) - the build is triggered

UPDATED: the issue with "only to the head commit of the branch" was on my side. Actually it triggers the build with tag added to any commit